# Check if string contains character within a group

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried this (using javascript):

```
"[a][\"][\"2]".replace(/(\[)[\"](\])/g, "$1replaced$2")
//checks for double quote between [ and ]
```

and this is returned

```
"[a][replaced]["2]"
```

So the current regex only checks for a single double-quote character("), how do I check if a string **contains** a `"` character within the matched group (between `[` and `]`)?

.

So the outcome I'm looking for is changing from this:

```
[a]["]["2]
```

to

```
[a][replaced][replaced2]
```

basically  replacing all double-quote characters within `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you want

```
"[a][\"][\"2][asdf\"1234]".replace(/(\[)([^\]]*)(\])/g, function (match, leftBr, guts, rightBr) {
  return leftBr + guts.replace(/\"/g, "replaced") + rightBr;
});
```

It grabs the guts of every bracket group and removes the quotes.

Comment: This doesn't check if it contains a `"` character, if you put a letter before the `"`, the `"` won't be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working approach:

```
\[[^\[]*"[^\]]*\]
```

I tested it with these strings:

```
[a]["]
[a]["]["2]
[a]["]["2]["3]["4]
```

Edit: this would also work with a string like this

```
[12"34]
```

Comment: This replaces everything within the `[` and `]` is there a way to **just** replace the `"` without affecting the rest?